# v-img image going out of screen

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to place two vuetify cards side by side and to take all the space of the parent div. The cards have images which are going out of the screen. I don't want to set a width. I want them to resize dynamically based on the display. I don't want them to respect the aspect-ratio. If the images gets cropped inside the card then that's fine. What am I doing wrong here in the code?

[Codesandbox to see the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-wing-044cm8?file=/src/App.vue:0-1891)

```
<template>
  <v-container class="about-section">
    <v-row class="d-none d-md-flex">
      <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="4">
        <div class="d-flex flex-start">Images</div>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="8">
        <div class="image-section">
          <v-card class="card-class">
            <v-img
              src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
              class="white--text align-end"
              height="250"
              gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
            >
              <v-card-title>hello</v-card-title>
            </v-img>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>

              <v-btn icon class="mr-3"> Visit<v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon> </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
          <v-card class="card-class" max-width="350">
            <v-img
              src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
              class="white--text align-end"
              cover
              height="250"
              gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
            >
              <v-card-title>hello</v-card-title>
            </v-img>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn icon class="mr-3">
                Visit
                <v-icon>mdi-share-variant</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.card-class {
  width: 100%;
}
.image-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.about-section {
  border-top: 1px solid #e6eaea;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.object-fit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple and let the grid system do the work for you...

```
  <v-container class="about-section">
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <div>Images</div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-row>
          <v-col sm="6">
            <v-card>
              <v-img
                src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
                class="white--text align-end"
                height="250"
                gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
              >
                <v-card-title>hello</v-card-title>
              </v-img>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn icon class="mr-3">
                  Visit<v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
          <v-col sm="6">
            <v-card>
              <v-img
                src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
                class="white--text align-end"
                cover
                height="250"
                gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
              >
                <v-card-title>hello</v-card-title>
              </v-img>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn icon class="mr-3">
                  Visit
                  <v-icon>mdi-share-variant</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-breeze-hxic0v?file=/src/App.vue:11-1543